# Dynamically divide array in several columns

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I'm working in Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I've got a collection of categories. So, I would like to list them in three columns per row, in groups of 10, and to have as many rows as needed. The ammount of categories can change, so the functionality should be dynamic.

Is there a "rails way" to accomplish this? or which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following railscasts episode:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of

The "in_groups_of" method should be exactly what you require:

```
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].in_groups_of(2, false)
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
```

The documentation for in_groups_of can be found at:

http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M001423&name=in_groups_of

Comment: Well, this is definitely the "rails way" :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is "rails way", but for sure it is "my way" ;)

```
# in controller
@categories = Category.all

# in view
<table>
  <% @categories.each_with_index do |cat, index| %>
    <%= "<tr>" if index % 30 == 0 %>
    <%= "<td>" if index % 10 == 0 %>
    <%= cat.name %>
    <%= "</td>" if (index + 1) % 10 == 0 || index + 1 == @categories.size %>
    <%= "</tr>" if (index + 1) % 30 == 0 || index + 1 == @categories.size %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

If you will switch to Rails 3, you have to add `raw` before putting any HTML tag inside `<%= %>`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try, although I prefer not to use tables. I would use <ul> or <div> instead. I think the logic changes a little bit, but I'll still try to make it work.